# Getting error in main activity on my basic calculator app

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple android calculator app. 
There is no compile time error, but when I'm tapping on any button, the app crashes.

```
package com.buckydroid.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView screen;
    private String str1,str2,str3,result,str,sign;
    private Double a,b;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        screen = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    }
    private void onClick(View v){
        Button button = (Button) v;
        str += button.getText().toString();
        screen.setText(str);
        a = Double.parseDouble(str);
        str = "";
    }
    private void onClickSigns(View v){
        Button button = (Button) v;
        sign = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
        screen.setText(sign);
        str="";
    }
    private void calculate(View v){
        Button button = (Button) v;
        str2 = screen.getText().toString();
        b = Double.parseDouble(str2);
        if (sign .equals("+")){
            result = a+b+"";
        }
        else if (sign .equals("-")){
            result = a-b+"";
        }
        else if (sign .equals("X")){
            result = a*b+"";
        }
        else if (sign .equals("÷")){
            result = a/b+"";
        }
        else{
            result = "Something went wrong";
        }
        screen.setText(result);
    }

}
```

Error Log

```
10-08 19:44:59.361 19449-19449/com.buckydroid.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.buckydroid.myapplication, PID: 19449
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So if you need any other code then please comment

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Can you paste your XML file? I am pretty sure the bug is in there on an `android:onClick` method.

Comment: Also I think your onClick methods here in the Java file all need to be `public` if they are to be seen by the XML file but I am not 100% sure on that one.

Comment: xD it's not taking more codes ... let me pastebin it @JustinConroy

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3byc2XDv pastebin link @JustinConroy

Comment: Made them public still not working :(

Comment: make your onclick method as public

Comment: Not working man @MohammedAtif

Comment: I can't see any reason why it shouldn't be working (especially with the `public` change). Sometimes when I see wierd stuff like this, I have to restart Android Studio, do Clean and Rebuild. Sometimes it helps...

Comment: let me do it too @JustinConroy

Comment: I am building your code in Android studio. I"ll let you know what I find.

Comment: can you update the xml file?

Comment: See revised answer below. I got it.

Comment: Thanx :) @JustinConroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it after building in Android studio. The error is a lot bigger than what you pasted and I was able to track it down with the stack trace.

Basically you are trying to concatenate a string to a null with this line in your `onClick` method: `str += button.getText().toString();`

Since you can't do that you can fix the issue by replacing:

```
str += button.getText().toString();
```

With this:

```
str = button.getText().toString();
```

OR

Since this is a calculator app, you can initialize `str` in the `onCreate` method with `str = "";` and then also remove `str = "";` from the `onClick` method.

Full Code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView screen;
private String str1,str2,str3,result,str,sign;
private Double a,b;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    screen = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    str = "";
}
public void onClick(View v){
    Button button = (Button) v;
    str += button.getText().toString();
    screen.setText(str);
    a = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
public void onClickSigns(View v){
    Button button = (Button) v;
    sign = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    screen.setText(sign);
    str="";
}
public void calculate(View v){
    Button button = (Button) v;
    str2 = screen.getText().toString();
    b = Double.parseDouble(str2);
    if (sign .equals("+")){
        result = a+b+"";
    }
    else if (sign .equals("-")){
        result = a-b+"";
    }
    else if (sign .equals("X")){
        result = a*b+"";
    }
    else if (sign .equals("÷")){
        result = a/b+"";
    }
    else{
        result = "Something went wrong";
    }
    screen.setText(result);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

onClick should be public not private.
also initialize your strings to empty string. Like:

```
private String str1 = "",str2="",str3="",result="",str="",sign="";
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Hey got the issue place. Updating the answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:
 in your main_activity xml file add android:onclick="onClick" and make onClick(View view) method public.

for example

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

And in main_activity.java file

```
public void onClick(View view){
}
```

Hope it help you :) Happy coding..